# SSL and iframe - Does the same certificate work for iframe?

Tags: ssl, iis, https, iis-7

I have a website embedding another website with iframe. The first website has SSL with a certificate for `*.something.com` and let's say its domain is `somethingelse.something.com`. Can I use the same certificate for the embedded website as well even though there is no subdomain in `something.com` referring to it?

In other words, does the fact that I am originally coming from `somethingelse.something.com` count for the embedded website as well?

I hope this makes sense, I am quite new with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the certificate is valid for the domain, **the fact that it's an iframe doesn't count.**
- Be careful: A certificate for "*.example.com" is valid for "anything.example.com" but **NOT for "example.com"**
- The iframe may be blocked for another reason:

  - CSP on the main page
  - X-FRAME-OPTIONS on the iframe

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, I'm just asking if it will work without getting the warning message from every browser. since `somethingelse.something.com` doesn't have a domain, I use the IP address, so I am unsure if the `*.something.com` certificate will work for that too.

So if I understood correctly your answer is that it will work?

Comment: You can't use your cert on an ip. You need a dns name ending .something.com to use your cert.

Comment: So for any confusions. There is no domain that points to the embedded website. I navigate there through the IP address. The certificate I'll use is `*.something.com` for both websites. But since I am entering the embedded website through the iframe which is in the `somethingelse.something.com` website, it should work for for it too right? Or will I get a warning from the browser that it is unsafe?

Comment: @A.Savva If the url of the browser is an ip or if the href of an iframe is an ip, the certificate MUST contains that ip to be valid. You probably don't have such certificate, so your browser will display a warning.

Comment: @Tom thanks, makes sense now. Is there a workaround for this that you know? We can't assign a domain to the embedded website.

Comment: @A.Savva why you can't? Is it open for everybody or only accessible for peoples of your company? If it's a public website, no  workaround, you need to get a domain. If it's an "internal" website, you can use a subdomain of your company's domain (or use a self-signed certificate and install it on every device that is supposed to connect to that domain - painful)

Comment: @Tom Unfortunately we have some reasons why we can't do that. There will be hundreds of these websites started automatically with an installation on hundreds of servers. Secondly, the domain registration is not handled internally, there is another company who handles it for us.

Comment: @A.Savva why can't you have ONE front domain that makes back-end api requests to theses hundreds of IPs ?

Comment: @A.Savva Or it can be subdomains like 45-65-12-03.youcompany.com that points to 45.65.12.03 on your dns level. Or 45-65-12-03.youcompany.com makes back-end api to 45.65.12.03

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169949/discussion-between-a-savva-and-tom).